# How to disable update notifications in High Sierra?

Tags: mac, notifications

I cant for the life of me figure out how to disable the notifications that persistently annoy me in High Sierra. These happen every single day at the top right of screen. A quick web search says that I need to disable them in some menu that is non-existent on my system:

[image]

As you can see in the next shot, I dont have the options shown in the previous photo:

[image]

I would like to either disable the notifications or disabled the updates. Whatever works to get rid of the notifications. Any help is appreciated.

Running OSX High Sierra

Answer (score -2):

<sub>People seem to dislike this answer, so let me emphasise the part that is the factual answer, before we get to the proposed solution…</sub>

## You can't disable System Notifications.

<sup>Right. Facts done with, back to the suggested solution…</sup>

So, instead, just do the updates. Your system is so far out of support that they will likely be the last updates you ever see.

The control panels in your top photo didn't appear until Mojave [the same time as system updates moved from the App Store to a dedicated Updates control panel], so you don't have the option of switching it off.

It goes without saying that a computer without current security updates is not safe on the internet.

You *can* right click & Hide Update, but I don't know if that will work for System Updates.

Comment: Downvoter - don't blame the messenger. Just because you don't like the answer doesn't make it a *bad* or inaccurate answer.